# NSPredicate with 20 last records

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm working with core data and I try to get last 20 records using `setFecthLimit` but in these last records I want to get count of unreads, I use this

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setFetchLimit:20];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isRead = NO OR isRead = NIL"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];                    

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *records = [[_managedObjectContext
                                            executeFetchRequest:request
                                            error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

but it always return me 20, can anyone help me please?

Comment: see http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=997921

Comment: thanks rachel for your reply but this example is different than mine. I work with the same entity. I can get this result using setFetchLimit:20 and after filter the result with checking isRead property but I want to know if i can do this in a more simple way.

Comment: sorry flexaddict, I try to explain. I want to fetch records with attribute "isRead == NO" but just in 10 last records, example of records:

 1. id 1 isRead = YES;
    - id 2 isRead = NO;
    - id 3 isRead = YES;
    - id 4 isRead = NO;
    - id 5 isRead = NO;
    - id 6 isRead = NO;
    - id 7 isRead = YES;
    - id 8 isRead = YES;
    - id 9 isRead = YES;
    - id 10 isRead = YES;
    - id 11 isRead = YES;
    - id 12 isRead = NO;
    - id 13 isRead = YES;
    - id 14 isRead = NO;
    - id 15 isRead = NO;
With these records I want to get just unreads in 20 last records, like these:
2, 4, 5, 6

Comment: Thank you for having removed your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to remove the predicate. Grab 20 objects and then filter them based on the predicate.

For example:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setFetchLimit:20];                    

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *records = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
                                                        error:&error];

// do some error checking here...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isRead = NO OR isRead = nil"];
// [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isRead = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
NSArray *filteredRecords = [records filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: thanks flexaddict, this is the approch I used, but I want to know if there is a simple way to do that.

Comment: @doc Based on my experience not. Maybe someone else could suggest other ways.

Comment: Thanks for your reply flexaddict.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your predicate format:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Post"]
request.fetchLimit = 20;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isRead == NO) OR (isRead == NULL)"];
NSSortDescriptor = [...insert your sort descriptor code here...]
request.sortDEscriptos = @[sd];
```

And remember to sort, such that you get the last 20, not just a random 20.